# Flutter doctor can't find sdkmanager

Tags: android, flutter, openjdk-11

So I'm trying to install flutter without Android Studio because my PC work really slow whenever i trying to open Android Studio. Everything working smoothly at beginning, but when flutter trying to get Android License using

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

it always give me

```
C:\Windows\System32>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.
```

and when i'm check using

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses -v
```

it give me

```
C:\Windows\System32>flutter doctor --android-licenses -v
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      AndroidLicenseValidator.runLicenseManager (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:422:7)
#2      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:295:38)
#3      DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:50:47)
#4      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1274:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

is there is anything wrong with my PATH or something hat i need to do first? I will include my path if that can help me.
[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you might be missing the command-line tools.

If you want to install the command-line tools without installing Android studio then I would suggest taking a look at this website [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line). It lists all the android sdk tools you can download without needing to install android studio.

If you do want to install android studio I was able to solve this problem just recently by going to Tools>SDK Manager>SDK Tools and selecting "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)", then hit okay to install the tools.

After you do that try doing `flutter doctor --android-licenses` again

Answer (score 1):

**N\B: I believe by default you had already installed thhe commandline tools.*
Go to the folder containing the sdkmanager.bat file and then open the cmd from there.
The cmd should show the folder in which it is open.
Run the following command, **'sdkmanager.bat --install "cmdline-tools;latest"**
After completely running the task close the cmd and open a new one and run 'flutter doctor'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For linux: 
`$ cd <your sdk folder>`
`$ cd cmdline-tools/tools/bin`
`$ ./sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into two issues.  I started with a default install of Android Studio and flutter from flatpack.

1. When you download `commandlinetools...zip` from Google, and unzip it, you get directories like `cmdline-tools/bin`, `cmdline-tools/lib` etc.  That doesn't work.  You need to create a `latest` subdirectory and move everything in there.  e.g. `/home/user/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/`
2. Now you can run the updater.  Something that works will look like `~/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=/home/user/Android/Sdk --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`.  When I first installed, instead of `/home/user/` I did `~/` and that caused problems subsequent to updating. The value you provide to `--sdk_root` gets cached somewhere.

Now you can run `flutter doctor` successfully to accept the licenses.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be solved from android studio go to SDK tools and click on android SDK command-line tools and install them.

Comment: If using android studio is the only available option then i will try it, but if it posible, i don't want to isntall android studio because of my PC is really low spec.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you may also need to set the android-sdk location. It's usually in `C:\$USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

You can set it by running `flutter config --android-sdk <path to android sdk>`.

This fixed the same issue for me.